# Possible to avoid cloning when returning the same option twice?

Tags: rust

I have a rather weird case where I need to return a option of a vec, both inside a struct, and just as as the option.
I made a small example here, which looks silly, but it's the same issue I have in a setting where it makes more sense (in the real world, the `container` represents a state to compute a next function, while the output option is a output to the user of my api)

```
pub struct Container {
    opt : Option<Vec<u8>>
}
pub fn return_option(plaintext: Vec<u8>) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    match plaintext.len() {
        l if l > 5 => None,
        _ => Some(plaintext)
    }
    
}

pub fn return_stuff(plaintext: Vec<u8>) -> (Container,Option<Vec<u8>>) {

    let dummycontainer = return_option(plaintext);

    return (Container{
        opt : dummycontainer.clone(),
    },
    dummycontainer)
    
}
```

So, the `return_stuff`, is the important one, in order not to have the compiler complain about the dummycontainer being a moved value.

In order to get around this, I clone the option, which sounds like an antipattern to me.

Is there any way around doing this, while still passing the options two different places?

**EDIT**

borrowing with a static lifetime seems to be the best route.
I just have no idea how. Trying to write the struct like this:

```
pub struct Container {
    opt : Option<&'a [u8]>
}
```

Is not allowed, and neither is:

```
pub fn return_stuff(plaintext: Vec<u8>) -> (Container,Option<&'a [u8]>) {
```

Comment: That depends on your needs. Do both `Container` and the second return value really *need* to hold ownership of a vector? Or would `Option<&'a [u8]>` suffice? "Ownership" is a very strong constraint. It implies that you need to be able to read, write, resize, move, and drop the value at will. If both need to be able to do that independently, then cloning is the right call. If they're both just reading from the vector, then a slice will do.

Comment: I tried playing with this, by defining the struct field as `Option<&'a [u8]>` , but it can't reckonize the lifetime, also I can't really get to define a slice inside of a option, I'm adding a edit with it

Comment: There may be an answer (I have some rough ideas), but the best thing to do is to not do it. And to help more with that, we need the real case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming someone else owns the `Vec<u8>` and everything you're talking about is strictly read-only, we can do the entire thing with slices. The original value can still be a `Vec<u8>`, but we're never passing ownership of that to any of the functions mentioned here.

```
pub struct Container<'a> {
  opt : Option<&'a [u8]>
}

pub fn return_option<'a>(plaintext: &'a [u8]) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
  match plaintext.len() {
    l if l > 5 => None,
    _ => Some(plaintext)
  }
}

pub fn return_stuff<'a>(plaintext: &'a [u8]) -> (Container<'a>,Option<&'a [u8]>) {
  let dummycontainer = return_option(plaintext);
  return (
    Container{
      opt: dummycontainer,
    },
    dummycontainer,
  )
}
```

If you've got a vector `my_vec`, you call these functions by borrowing it, as `return_stuff(&my_vec[..])`.

Comment: RE last sentence, `&my_vec` without the `[..]` will frequently work because of `Vec`'s `Deref` implementation.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks! I've been writing Rust for about four years now, and I still haven't fully grokked when `Deref` will kick in yet.

Comment: Yeah, its a bit eh. If the compiler knows it needs what an object de-references to, it works ok, but when working with generics, it might not know what it needs and an explicit slicing or `as_slice` is needed.